# WPF Printing Large Canvas over multiple Pages

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, dynamic, printing

I've got this problem:
I created a pretty large Canvas in WPF with a lot children.
I want to add a Print Button. PrintVisual seems not to work, because the image is to big. (I am using a scrollbar) I want to split the Canvas between multiple pages.
What i've done so far:

1. I am taking a Visual Brush for every part of the Canvas
2. Create a new Canvas and make the visual brush its background
3. Adding the new Canvas to a page, add the page to a FixedDocument.

Well, now i've got a FixedDocument and going to print it via printDocument.
The Problem is, that the whole process of printing takes a lot of time and sometimes it doesn't work at all. It's like there is a preprocessing step to convert the fixed document into a bitmap.
My Question: Is a Visualbrush in a Canvas to big? Should i convert the Canvas first into a bitmap?
I've found this great article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339416/Printing-large-WPF-UserControls.
Whatever.

Is it a good way to convert a huge canvas into a bitmap first and then print parts of the bitmap? I could very well imagine, that one could get problems with blurring effects this way.
I've got also no idea how to add a bitmap to a page in wpf.

The worst thing is, that i couldn't found some really good sorces or a standardway (and i think there has to be one, cause this should be a pretty standard problem) for printing dynamic produced canvas in wpf.
I am really greatful for every really good source, help or code.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: How about boxing your Canvas into a ViewBox and add this ViewBox to your FixedDocument?

Comment: use BlockUIContainer for UI elements.

Comment: @unkreativ Why should i do something like that? The whole canvas in one page is too small.

Comment: My understanding is, that your question was how to print the canvas because it is to big for the page. That's why I suggested the ViewBox. Your comment indicates me that you try to split the canvas on multiple pages? If so, your question was missleading

Comment: You are right. This is exactly what i'am trying to do. Printing one page is pretty easy. I should edit the question